# subprocess-exited-with-error while trying to install pydoop

Tags: python, hadoop

I'm trying to install pydoop on my ubuntu but ended with the following errors.

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pydoop
  Running setup.py clean for pydoop
Failed to build pydoop
Installing collected packages: pydoop
  Running setup.py install for pydoop ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for pydoop did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [79 lines of output]
      using setuptools version 65.6.3
      running install
      /home/manoj/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop
      copying pydoop/config.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop
      copying pydoop/hadoop_utils.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop
      copying pydoop/hadut.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop
      copying pydoop/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop
      copying pydoop/test_support.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop
      copying pydoop/test_utils.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop
      copying pydoop/avrolib.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop
      copying pydoop/jc.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop
      copying pydoop/version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/mapreduce
      copying pydoop/mapreduce/binary_protocol.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/mapreduce
      copying pydoop/mapreduce/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/mapreduce
      copying pydoop/mapreduce/pipes.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/mapreduce
      copying pydoop/mapreduce/api.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/mapreduce
      copying pydoop/mapreduce/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/mapreduce
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/hdfs
      copying pydoop/hdfs/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/hdfs
      copying pydoop/hdfs/file.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/hdfs
      copying pydoop/hdfs/fs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/hdfs
      copying pydoop/hdfs/path.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/hdfs
      copying pydoop/hdfs/common.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/hdfs
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/app
      copying pydoop/app/argparse_types.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/app
      copying pydoop/app/submit.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/app
      copying pydoop/app/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/app
      copying pydoop/app/main.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/app
      copying pydoop/app/script.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/app
      copying pydoop/app/script_template.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/app
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/utils
      copying pydoop/utils/misc.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/utils
      copying pydoop/utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/utils
      copying pydoop/utils/conversion_tables.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/utils
      copying pydoop/utils/py3compat.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/utils
      copying pydoop/utils/jvm.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/utils
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/hdfs/core
      copying pydoop/hdfs/core/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/hdfs/core
      copying pydoop/pydoop.properties -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop
      running build_ext
      checking for TLS support
      creating /tmp/pydoop_6tyh2mvj/tmp
      creating /tmp/pydoop_6tyh2mvj/tmp/pydoop_6tyh2mvj
      aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c /tmp/pydoop_6tyh2mvj/temp.c -o /tmp/pydoop_6tyh2mvj/tmp/pydoop_6tyh2mvj/temp.o
      building 'pydoop.native_core_hdfs' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/common
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/os
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/os/posix
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/native_core_hdfs
      aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DHAVE_BETTER_TLS -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include -Inative/jni_include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/lib -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include/linux -Isrc/libhdfs -Isrc/libhdfs/include -Isrc/libhdfs/os/posix -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/libhdfs/common/htable.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/common/htable.o -Wno-write-strings
      aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DHAVE_BETTER_TLS -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include -Inative/jni_include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/lib -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include/linux -Isrc/libhdfs -Isrc/libhdfs/include -Isrc/libhdfs/os/posix -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/libhdfs/exception.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/exception.o -Wno-write-strings
      aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DHAVE_BETTER_TLS -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include -Inative/jni_include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/lib -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include/linux -Isrc/libhdfs -Isrc/libhdfs/include -Isrc/libhdfs/os/posix -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/libhdfs/hdfs.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/hdfs.o -Wno-write-strings
      aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DHAVE_BETTER_TLS -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include -Inative/jni_include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/lib -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include/linux -Isrc/libhdfs -Isrc/libhdfs/include -Isrc/libhdfs/os/posix -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/libhdfs/jni_helper.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/jni_helper.o -Wno-write-strings
      aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DHAVE_BETTER_TLS -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include -Inative/jni_include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/lib -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include/linux -Isrc/libhdfs -Isrc/libhdfs/include -Isrc/libhdfs/os/posix -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/libhdfs/os/posix/mutexes.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/os/posix/mutexes.o -Wno-write-strings
      aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DHAVE_BETTER_TLS -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include -Inative/jni_include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/lib -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include/linux -Isrc/libhdfs -Isrc/libhdfs/include -Isrc/libhdfs/os/posix -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/libhdfs/os/posix/thread.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/os/posix/thread.o -Wno-write-strings
      aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DHAVE_BETTER_TLS -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include -Inative/jni_include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/lib -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include/linux -Isrc/libhdfs -Isrc/libhdfs/include -Isrc/libhdfs/os/posix -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/libhdfs/os/posix/thread_local_storage.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/os/posix/thread_local_storage.o -Wno-write-strings
      aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DHAVE_BETTER_TLS -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include -Inative/jni_include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/lib -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include/linux -Isrc/libhdfs -Isrc/libhdfs/include -Isrc/libhdfs/os/posix -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/native_core_hdfs/hdfs_file.cc -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/native_core_hdfs/hdfs_file.o -Wno-write-strings
      aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DHAVE_BETTER_TLS -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include -Inative/jni_include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/lib -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include/linux -Isrc/libhdfs -Isrc/libhdfs/include -Isrc/libhdfs/os/posix -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/native_core_hdfs/hdfs_fs.cc -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/native_core_hdfs/hdfs_fs.o -Wno-write-strings
      aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DHAVE_BETTER_TLS -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include -Inative/jni_include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/lib -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/include/linux -Isrc/libhdfs -Isrc/libhdfs/include -Isrc/libhdfs/os/posix -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/native_core_hdfs/hdfs_module.cc -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/native_core_hdfs/hdfs_module.o -Wno-write-strings
      aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/common/htable.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/exception.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/hdfs.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/jni_helper.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/os/posix/mutexes.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/os/posix/thread.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/libhdfs/os/posix/thread_local_storage.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/native_core_hdfs/hdfs_file.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/native_core_hdfs/hdfs_fs.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/native_core_hdfs/hdfs_module.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/Libraries -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/jre/lib/aarch64/server -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -ldl -ljvm -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pydoop/native_core_hdfs.cpython-310-aarch64-linux-gnu.so -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/jre/lib/aarch64/server
      building 'pydoop.sercore' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/sercore
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/sercore/HadoopUtils
      aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -Isrc/sercore/HadoopUtils -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/sercore/HadoopUtils/SerialUtils.cc -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/sercore/HadoopUtils/SerialUtils.o -Wno-write-strings -std=c++11 -O3
      src/sercore/HadoopUtils/SerialUtils.cc:21:10: fatal error: rpc/types.h: No such file or directory
         21 | #include <rpc/types.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pydoop

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I've tried upgrading and downgrading pip versions and I've tried everything that I could. I'm using python version 3.10.6 and pip version 22.3.1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As the error says, pip isn't the problem. It's `No such file or directory`

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use pydoop over pyspark or mrjob?

Comment: I'm using Kafka to get real time data from kafkaProducer and trying to use pydoop to insert that data to hdfs from kafkaConsumer.